# Run JSP/Servlet program in differentlocation

Tags: jsp, servlets

How can I run or execute my jsp application which is located at different drive?
My appache is in c:\Programs... and my application is in the D drive

Answer (score 0):

[Define a context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context) with the appropriate `docBase` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code something like this

<%=request.getContextPath()%>/jsp/usermanagement/StudentOperations.jsp">

This is a common way of executing files in a different path. It automatically searches for the path.

Please explore request.getContextPath() makes your job much easier.

You can assign whatever path you feel like.